# The set of integrable real-valued functions on $X$ is a real vector space.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm aware that this question has been asked several times and over: however, I remain unsatisfied.

The textbook I'm working with is *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications (2nd Edition)* by Gerald Folland, with the question I have pertaining to Proposition 2.21.

> **2.21 Proposition.** The set of integrable real-valued functions on $X$ is a real vector space, and the integral is a linear functional on it.

The proof for showing that the set in question is a vector space involves invoking the triangle inequality $|af+bg|\leq|a||f|+|b||g|$: this part makes sense. The question I have is whether the function $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f$ will also be integrable? Folland states that a real-valued function $f$ is integrable iff $\int f<\infty$...however, if we define $f(x)=1$, then $\int|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f|$ is no longer finite thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f$ is not integrable. From this we should be able to deduce that the set of all integrable real-valued functions is not closed under addition, hence cannot be a vector space, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: what does the integrability of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ have to do with being a vector space?

Comment: Closed under addition means addition of two elements, or by induction any finite number of elements, but not addition of infinitely many elements

Comment: @J.W.Tanner According to the Wikipedia definition of a vector space, the set of all integrable functions would need to be a group under addition (in this case). If you add an element with itself in a group an infinite number of times, it should still be in the group, no? // EDIT: I think I see what you're saying now. I just need to become better familiarized with group theory. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No; group addition maps two elements to the sum element, and any finitely many elements can be added, but adding an element with itself in a group an infinite number of times is not defined within the group; consider the group of integers under addition

Comment: For a group you only need to check for finite sums, anything involving infinite summation will have to use some sort of additional structure like a topology to even define properly.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3560460/group-only-closed-under-finite-composition-examples-and-counterexamples) help?

Comment: By comparison, do you have any problem with, say, $\mathbb{R}^2$ being a vector space? Then what happens if you do something like $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (1, 0)$?

Comment: Hey all, sorry for the delay: yes, what you all had said was very helpful! I'm only an undergraduate so seemingly trivial properties such as these can sometimes trip me up. I was unaware the statement $f+g$ is equivalent to simply stating that the set is closed specifically under finite sum. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A group or vector space being closed under addition means addition of two elements, or by induction any finite number of elements, but not addition of infinitely many elements. For example, in the additive group of integers, $1+1+1+1+\cdots$ is not in the group, although $1+1+1+\cdots+1$ is.